# c3 click and highlight multiple selections

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, c3.js

I am trying to build a prototype to highlight multiple points on a bar chart when the user clicks on it. I am not able to select multiple points.

If I try to change the style individually like, this highlights the clicked bar. I wanted to use the css class .solid so the next times the user clicks it i can look up the items with that class and retain them. The following works but its setting the opacity individually

```
 d3.selectAll(k).style("opacity", 1)
```

If I try to add a class like using the .classed is not working.

```
 d3.selectAll(k).classed('solid', true);
```

I have shared a plunker link to show the problem. Can someone please let me know how i can apply the css class to multiple items and then access the items with selectAll each time the user clicks on a bar to add the new item to the highlighted items. Thanks for your help.

[C3 Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YC3Qt8mJkjNfmsu6mV38?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Well this works as expected:
Add this in your style:

```
.solid{
  opacity:0.3 !important;
}
```

Then in your click do as you suggesting.

```
      onclick: function(e) {
        //add solid style to all bars.
        d3.selectAll(".c3-shape").classed("solid", true);//add to all bar this class
        var k = ".c3-shape-" + e.index;
        //make the clicked bar opacity 1
        d3.selectAll(k).classed("solid", false);//remove class solid from the clicked bar.
      }
```

working code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/dCD6cfBMR4PB6Q9m7Hsm?p=preview)